# how to insert text between two bullet list in ms word using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm creating ms word document using apache poi. I want to insert some texts between two bullet list but I could not do it. I wrote this codes to do it.

```
    if(!egeneral.get(i).equals(egeneral.get((i+1)%egeneral.size())))
        {
            XWPFParagraph baslik2Para = document.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun baslik2 = baslik2Para.createRun();
            baslik2.setFontSize(10);
            baslik2.setBold(true);
            if(!egeneral.get(i).equals("What is the configuration of the DEP?"))
            {
                baslik2.setText(egeneral.get(i).toString());
                baslik2.addBreak();
                if(egeneral.get(i).equals("Engine Condition"))
                {
                    while(eg_answers.next())
                    {
                        ans.add(eg_answers.getString("strGEN01"));
                        ans.add(eg_answers.getString("strGEN02"));
                        ans.add(eg_answers.getString("strGEN03"));
                        ans.add(eg_answers.getString("strVane"));
                        ans.add(eg_answers.getString("strPlate"));
                        ans.add(eg_answers.getString("strGEN04"));
                        ans.add(eg_answers.getString("strGEN05"));
                        ans.add(eg_answers.getString("strGEN06"));

                      }

                    CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = CTAbstractNum.Factory.newInstance();
                    cTAbstractNum.setAbstractNumId(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
                    CTLvl cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
                    cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.BULLET);
                    cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("•");
                    XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);
                    XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();
                    BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);
                    BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID); 
                    for (String string : ans) {
                        XWPFParagraph bulletedPara = document.createParagraph();
                        XWPFRun baslik3 = bulletedPara.createRun();
                        baslik3.setFontSize(10);
                        baslik3.setText(string); 
                        if(string.equals("ACC Valve removable plug configuration is as follows:"))
                        {
                            XWPFParagraph accPara = document.createParagraph();
                            XWPFRun acc = accPara.createRun();
                            acc.setText("Qty In Vane: "+eg_answers.getString("strVane"));
                            acc.addBreak();
                            acc.setText("Qty In storage plate:"+eg_answers.getString("strPlate"));
                            acc.addBreak();
                        }
                        bulletedPara.setNumID(numID);

                    }
                }
            }  
        }
```

When I run this codes, it gives me this errors. I don't understand why it gives me this errors. I'm getting datas at access database.

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.7 invalid cursor state: identifier cursor not positioned on row in UPDATE, DELETE, SET, or GET statement: ; ResultSet is positioned after last row
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getString(UcanaccessResultSet.java:695)
    at access_read_and_write.access_connection.answers(access_connection.java:1617)
    at access_read_and_write.access_connection.Start(access_connection.java:204)
    at Servlet.shop_visit_report.doGet(shop_visit_report.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
```

Comment: Is file `shop_visit_report.java` one that you wrote? Which line of that file is line 55 ?

Comment: @Abra the `shop_visit_report.java` is my servlet. This is the line 55 in **shop_visit_report.java** `access_connection.Start(salesorder,path);` .

Comment: Excuse me, my mistake. I now see from the stack trace you posted that the exception is thrown in file `access_connection.java` at line 1617. Did you post that line?

Comment: @Abra yes, line 1617 is `XWPFParagraph accPara = document.createParagraph();`

Comment: Is `document` an instance of class `XWPFDocument` ?

Comment: The error is a `JDBC` error thrown by result set `getString` method. The code line `XWPFParagraph accPara = document.createParagraph();` cannot throw that error.  I suspect it comes from `eg_answers.getString("strVane")`. And this is pretty clear since you walked through the whole result set using `while(eg_answers.next())` already. So there is nothing more to get.

Comment: @AxelRichter The error stems from **if(string.equals("ACC Valve removable plug configuration is as follows:"))** I changed it to **if(ans.equals("ACC Valve removable plug configuration is as follows:"))** but I can't still add paragraph between two bullet.

Comment: According your code snippet `ans` seems to be a `List`. How shall a `List` equals a `String`? No, the reason for the error is exactly the one I commented already. But a really answer is not possible because we don not have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).